# Program that reads line by line and put info into a array

Tags: c

I have a program that has to read numbers from a file and put them into a array. The problem is that the program is not putting the last number into the array. The array has to be a char array because of the specifications of the exercice.
Here it goes the code:

```
 char line[RSIZ][LSIZ];
 FILE *fptr = NULL; 
 int i = 0;
 fptr = fopen("casosproduto.txt", "rt");
 while(fgets(line[i], LSIZ, fptr)!=NULL) 
 {

 line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';  
 i++;
 } 


 fclose(fptr);
```

I know that is something because of the line :` line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';

but I'm not sure how to solve it.Any solution for my problem?

Comment: That will fail if the last line in the file has no newline ending. Try `line[i][ strcspn(line[i], "\n") ] = 0;`. It is bullet proof.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I tried that way. unfortunately is not passing the last line of the file to the array. Can't understand why

Comment: In that case please edit the question to show a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. The best way to do that is by copy/paste, after you check it compiles and does exhibit the behaviour described. Also post the text file that you are working with.

Comment: If you are just reading numbers and know the type, you can read them into an array of numbers (let's say `int`) using `fscanf()`. Would be easier to work with. And of course, we can't help much without you following Weather Vane's above suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
line[i][strlen(line[i]) - 1] = '\0';  
i++;
```

results in `i` indicating a 'row' in the array that has not been filled with data from the input file,

This is to be expected and not a problem.